# как сделать стартовый url в react?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

как сделать стартовый url в react? чтобы при включении сайта вместо `'/'` было изначально `'/home'`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `<Redirect exact from="/" to="home" />`

Answer (score 1):

```
<Route exact path="/">
    <Redirect to="/home" />
</Route>
```